# Error while dynamically renaming SAS Dataset

Tags: sas, dataset

**BACKGROUND**

I have a script that runs every month creating the dataset to be used by my team.  The script generates datasets in my personal UNIX directory, I then run sanity checks and copy the dataset to a "public" directory where my team can access it.  The script is stable so there is no need to run sanity checks anymore.

**WHAT I WANT TO DO**

- Extract the last modified date from previous version of the dataset from the public folder (Working fine)
- Upend the previous dataset name with modified
  date (facing issues)
- Move/copy the newly created dataset to public folder (Working fine)

**PROBLEM STATEMENT**

I am getting following error while attempting to change the dataset name

> ERROR: You cannot rename COSTDATA.EMPL_CHAIN.DATA to COSTDATA.EMPL_CHAIN_19SEP18.DATA because COSTDATA.EMPL_CHAIN.DATA is in use by you in resource environment IOM ROOT COMP ENV.

**CODE USED**

```
%let dsid2=%sysfunc(open(costdata.empl_chain));
%put ********&dsid2;
%let modte2=%sysfunc(attrn(&dsid2,modte),datetime7.);
%put &modte2;
%let rc=%sysfunc(close(&dsid2));
%put RC Value is &rc;

proc datasets library=costdata;
change empl_chain=empl_chain_&modte2;
run;
```

**SAS LOG**

```
29         %let dsid2=%sysfunc(open(costdata.empl_chain));
30         %put ********&dsid2;
********2
31         %let modte2=%sysfunc(attrn(&dsid2,modte),datetime7.);
32         %put &modte2;
19SEP18
33         %let rc=%sysfunc(close(&dsid2));
34         %put RC Value is &rc;
RC Value is 0
35         


36         proc datasets library=costdata;
37         change empl_chain=empl_chain_&modte2;
38         run;

NOTE: Changing the name COSTDATA.EMPL_CHAIN to COSTDATA.EMPL_CHAIN_19SEP18 (memtype=DATA).
ERROR: You cannot rename COSTDATA.EMPL_CHAIN.DATA to COSTDATA.EMPL_CHAIN_19SEP18.DATA because COSTDATA.EMPL_CHAIN.DATA is in use by you in resource environment IOM ROOT COMP ENV.
39
```

*Other helpful information:*

I am trying to do the similar operation to multiple datasets.  The rename piece works fine for the first dataset if the SAS EG session is new.  It predictably fails for second dataset onward. In EG, Tools > Options > Data > Data General... the 'Automatically open data when added to project' checkbox is Unchecked as suggested by SAS.

I am also aware of other simple tricks such as declaring a new dataset with correct name in a new data step or using 'exchange' function in proc dataset.  I would like to know however, if there is any solution to the above error.

Comment: Do you get any errors earlier? I do when I try and run your code.

Answer (score 0):

https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/sysfunc-open-causes-table-to-be-locked-if-error-occurs/td-p/57601 discusses a series of causes

Including:

- `LOCK`ed members
- Held open by client (EG) settings
- Opened with errors and no checks on `open` function

What is the dsid returned from the second `%sysfunc(open` attempt and the `%sysfunc(sysmsg())` ?

Can you ssh into your Unix host and issue a command to [list lockers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85994/how-to-list-processes-locking-file) ? Commands such as `flock` `lslock`, `lslk`, `lsof`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to get the modified date another way.

```
%let dset = CLASS;

proc sql noprint;
select put(datepart(modate), yymmddn8.) into :modte
from sashelp.vtable
where libname='WORK' and memname="&dset.";
quit;

%put &modte.;


proc datasets library=work;
change &dset. = &dset._&modte.;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm lost.  Your code runs fine for me, from EG 7.15 talking to SAS 9.4M4 session on linux. Below is an example, using WORK library.  Can you use see if this reproduces the problem in your environment, and if not, can you post full code that does reproduce the problem using data created from SASHELP datasets?

From the log you shared, it looks like all the return codes are good, so the SAS code shouldn't be locking the file.  Once you have a reproducible example, maybe try batch submitting it on the server (assuming you can access via ssh), just to see if EG is somehow causing the lock.

```
data class ;
  set sashelp.class ;
run ;

data shoes ;
  set sashelp.shoes ;
run ;

%let dsid2=%sysfunc(open(work.class));
%put ********&dsid2;
%let modte2=%sysfunc(attrn(&dsid2,modte),datetime7.);
%put &modte2;
%let rc=%sysfunc(close(&dsid2));
%put RC Value is &rc;

proc datasets library=work;
change class=class_&modte2;
run;

%let dsid2=%sysfunc(open(work.shoes));
%put ********&dsid2;
%let modte2=%sysfunc(attrn(&dsid2,modte),datetime7.);
%put &modte2;
%let rc=%sysfunc(close(&dsid2));
%put RC Value is &rc;

proc datasets library=work;
change shoes=shoes_&modte2;
run;
```

Comment: I am unable to recreate the problem using sashelp datasets.  The code on similar lines works just fine.  My belief is that the datasets are being used by some other program like spotfire.  I think I need to rewrite using proc datasets "Exchange".  Exchange will allow datasets to be modified while they are being consumed by other programs.

Comment: Agree it’s possible an external process (eg backup or virus scan) is causing a file lock. If that’s the case, I wouldn’t think EXCHANGE would help any. It’s probably doing the same thing as two RENAMEs.